# state: check-failed when running canonical-livepatch

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I have just installed the canonical livepatch snap package:

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
sudo canonical-livepatch enable (and the code)
```

I also setup unattended upgrades:

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

However, when I want to check on the livepatch status by doing:

```
canonical-livepatch status --verbose
```

I get this:

```
client-version: "5"
machine-id: a144ba7b92ec478495cc5918743fe0e7
machine-token: 46a92999127246328b5091f493ee7be0
architecture: x86_64
cpu-model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 430  @ 2.27GHz
last-check: 2016-11-02T11:38:33.551353308+02:00
boot-time: 2016-11-02T11:40:22+02:00
uptime: 12m0s
status:
- kernel: 4.4.0-45.66-generic
  running: true
  livepatch:
    state: check-failed
    version: ""
    fixes: ""
```

Should I be concerned with the **state: check-failed** message? If so, what is causing it, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This may solve your issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-livepatch-client/+bug/1655458/comments/5

Comment: Note that Canonical only supports up to 3 machines per free account, supposedly.  That may cause issues if you try to register more than 3 machines on the same token.  Though, some have said they had no problems registering more than 3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be concerned. I have this problem too. The best I could do is to disable and re-enable livepatching every day (it works for a few hours, then stops).

You can look at the log:

```
# systemctl status snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
```

For some reason, it stops authenticate with the service after a while:

```
● snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service - Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-10-22 11:38:29 EDT; 1 weeks 3 days ago
 Main PID: 8435 (canonical-livep)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
           └─8435 /snap/canonical-livepatch/15/canonical-livepatchd

Nov 02 03:39:08 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: No payload available.
Nov 02 04:39:09 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: Checking with livepatch service.
Nov 02 04:39:09 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: Bad server status code: 403. URL: https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine/<id> {"error": "Invalid Machine Token"}
Nov 02 04:39:09 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: No payload available.
Nov 02 05:39:09 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: Checking with livepatch service.
Nov 02 05:39:09 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: Bad server status code: 403. URL: https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine/<id> {"error": "Invalid Machine Token"}
Nov 02 05:39:09 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: No payload available.
Nov 02 06:39:09 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: Checking with livepatch service.
Nov 02 06:39:09 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: Bad server status code: 403. URL: https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine/<id> {"error": "Invalid Machine Token"}
Nov 02 06:39:09 firstborn canonical-livepatch[8435]: No payload available.
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes across this issue, this worked for me:

```
sudo rm /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id && sudo systemd-machine-id-setup
```

then

```
sudo canonical-livepatch enable XXXXyourtokenIDXXXX
```